# Angular - iOS Blank Pages

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, mobile-safari

I've just installed Angular and I'm facing two blank page problems:

**1) Blank Angular.io Website On iOS 7**

My iPad (running iOS 7) just sees a blank page when I try to load the [Angular.io](https://angular.io) website, both via Safari and Chrome apps. I thought iOS 7 is supported by Angular ([source](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)), isn't it? It does display properly on my iPhone running iOS 9.

It is important that the Angular website I will build can be viewed properly on older devices too, so I wanted to know if it has problems supporting iOS 7.

**2) Blank Mobile Page With Ng Serve**

I installed the Angular [test app](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) and I can see the test page fine on my computer browsers (both local and networked computers).

However, if I load it on my iPhone or iPad, the page is completely blanked, both on Safari and Chrome apps. I do see the tab's title "My App", so it is able to connect properly to my `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` but the page just does not render. It does render fine on my Android 7 device's stock & Chrome browsers.

I've connected my iPhone / iPad's Safari to my Mac's Safari inspector, and got the following errors when loading the My App demo page:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0 (vendor.bundle.js:514)
__webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
(anonymous function) (main.bundle.js:66)
__webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
webpackJsonpCallback (inline.bundle.js:26)
```

As for Angular.io website, the following error shows:

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WeakMap
LMZF (main.7d151f1f7f0a94ae41e1.bundle.js:1:142339)
n (inline.ad7fd106f6c55b1fd8ed.bundle.js:1:106)
cDNt (main.7d151f1f7f0a94ae41e1.bundle.js:1:284246)
n (inline.ad7fd106f6c55b1fd8ed.bundle.js:1:106)
(anonymous function) (main.7d151f1f7f0a94ae41e1.bundle.js:1:2317)
n (inline.ad7fd106f6c55b1fd8ed.bundle.js:1:106)
webpackJsonp (inline.ad7fd106f6c55b1fd8ed.bundle.js:1:430)
```

I tried searching around and some solutions mentioned about updating webpack-dev-server, enabling polyfills, or changing tsconfig.json to es5, all of which I tried but it didn't seem to work.

Can someone please advise? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure but have you attempted using any of the polyfills suggested on that page?  Would probably help to know which version of Safari that is, also you will typically see requests come in at the terminal with temporary web servers like this (not sure about what ng serve uses exactly).

Comment: Thanks, I tried enabling polyfills but it didn't seem to solve the problem. Then I connected the iPad to web inspector on Mac, and saw this error: "[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'". The es6 polyfill I enabled in polyfills.ts didn't seem to work... am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry don't know myself hopefully someone else who has dealt with this already stumbles across this.  const is something that you would think would be covered under ES6 polyfills, but hard to say, sounds like you're on the right path to debugging the issue but unfortunately I don't have anything to add at this point.

Comment: No worries at all, thank you for your suggestions and help!